# Why does this code work for counting one item in a list but not the others?

Tags: javascript, function, d3.js, dc.js

I am using trying to count the number of "Manager"'s "MIT"'s and "Instore"'s in a .csv file. The code I have works for finding all the "Manager"'s but wont work for the other two.

I've tried splitting the function up into 3 separate functions as I thought the problem may have been using more than one dc.numberDisplay in a function but that didn't work. I've tried the function so there's only one, if it's looking for Managers it works, MIT's it does not and Instores it does not. I've tried changing the order of the code and still nothing. I've put console.log(p.mit_count) within each line of add_item, remove_item and initialise. I've put console.log(d.value.mit_count) within the valueAccessor.

```
Scott,Instore,3,BMC,96
Mark,Instore,4,Intro,94
Wendy,Instore,3,Intro,76
Lucas,Instore,2,Intro,96
```

```
    .defer(d3.csv, "data/Results.csv")
    .await(makeGraphs)

//function for making and rendering graphs
function makeGraphs(error, staffData) {
    var ndx = crossfilter(staffData);
    show_number_of_staff(ndx);
    dc.renderAll();
}

function show_number_of_staff(ndx) {
    var dim = ndx.dimension(dc.pluck('Rank'));

    function add_item(p, v) {
        if (v.Rank == "Manager") {
            p.manager_count++;
        }
        else if (v.Rank == "MIT") {
            p.mit_count++;
        }
        else if (v.Rank == "Instore") {
            p.instore_count++;
        }
        return p;
    }

    function remove_item(p, v) {
        if (v.Rank == "Manager") {
            p.manager_count--;
        }
        else if (v.Rank == "MIT") {
            p.mit_count--;
        }
        else if (v.Rank == "Instore") {
            p.instore_count--;
        }
        return p;
    }

    function initialise(p, v) {
        return { manager_count: 0, mit_count: 0, instore_count: 0 };

    }

    var staffCounter = dim.group().reduce(add_item, remove_item, initialise);;

    dc.numberDisplay("#managerCount")
        .formatNumber(d3.format(".0"))
        .valueAccessor(function(d) {
            return d.value.manager_count;
        })
        .group(staffCounter);

    dc.numberDisplay("#mitCount")
        .formatNumber(d3.format(".0"))
        .valueAccessor(function(d) {
            return d.value.mit_count;
        })
        .group(staffCounter);

    dc.numberDisplay("#instoreCount")
        .formatNumber(d3.format(".0"))
        .valueAccessor(function(d) {
            return d.value.instore_count;
        })
        .group(staffCounter);
}
```

`console.log(p.mit_count)` shows that it counts to 13 (as I am expecting it to), but then in the `valueAccessor` `console.log(d.value.mit_count)` shows 0. I cannot get why this works for "Manager" but nothing else. I'm almost embarrassed that this has taken me over a week. It just seems so simple!

Comment: What happens when you change the order of the `dc.numberDisplay`s so that mitCount is first for example?

Comment: The result stays the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you log `staffCounter.all()` you'll find that it is counting managers, MITs, and Instores in 3 separate bins. This is because your dimension is sorting by `Rank`, then your group is binning again by `Rank`, so you end up with one bin per rank.

Normally you will want to pass a [groupAll object](https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#crossfilter_groupAll), with one bin, to the numberDisplay. However, it is permissive and will also accept ordinary groups with multiple bins ([source](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/6cae5353e6f2390c6a9ea0426579c38e251622d2/src/number-display.js#L91)). It will sort the bins and take the last.

Why? I'm not sure. I think in almost every case you will want to reduce to one bin, but someone clearly had a use case where they wanted to display the largest value out of many bins.

I was surprised to find that the behavior is not documented, so I've updated [the numberDisplay documentation](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.numberDisplay.html).

With a `groupAll` your code will look something like:

```
var staffCounter = ndx.groupAll().reduce(add_item, remove_item, initialise);
dc.numberDisplay("#managerCount")
    .formatNumber(d3.format(".0"))
    .valueAccessor(function(d) {
        return d.manager_count; // no .value here
    })
    .group(staffCounter);
```

Note that no crossfilter dimension is used here.

Comment: You're like a wee guardian angel. That works perfectly. I really appreciate the help you've given. You've solved this problem for me and my previous problem. Can't thank you enough.